# MPLAB X, XC8, and C in general. Using variables across functions and source files

Tags: c, function, variables, pic, mplab

I am having a difficult time passing variables to functions--especially functions that are not in the same source file.  I suspect these two problems are actually the same problem.  I am sure this is somewhere on the internet, but I have done a lot of searching and I am now even more confused.  Mostly I need someone to give me some direction on what I should be reading/searching for.

PROBLEM 1:

Say I have a source file named main.c.  After the #includes and #defines, I declare a variable

```
int count;
```

I then declare a function

```
void increment () {
count++;
}
```

Within function main(); I call the function increment();, and then update PORTA to display it in LEDs.  Both "count" and PORTA are assigned zero before main(); runs.

```
void main () {
     increment();
     PORTA = count;
}
```

The problem is that there appears to be two versions of "count".  If this program was run, PORTA would never light an LED.  However, if "PORTA = count;" were moved inside the function, it would increment properly.  Furthermore, all hardware writes (Port, tris, etc) work fine inside the function, but variables I thought I declared globally do not.  Thus, I assume the compiler is making a copy of "count" for the function call, and forgetting it when it returns.

I would normally just return a value from the function to get around this, but interrupt routines for the PIC cannot return a value, and I must use an interrupt.

What do I do?  Surely I am missing a major concept!

PROBLEM 2: Example of a common issue

Say I am using the MLA device library and load the demo material for the HID_Mouse.  Though it has ten million folders and source and header files that include each other, I am able to edit some of the subroutines and make it do my bidding.  However, I need to declare a variable that is used both in main.c and modified by a function in app_device_mouse.c.  How do I declare this thing so that it gets globally read/written, but I don't get declaration errors from the compiler?

```
../src/app_device_mouse.c:306: error: (192) undefined identifier "position_x"
```

i.e "You didn't declare 'int position_x' in app_device_mouse.c, even though you did in main.c

I'm not sure of the result of declaring it in both places, but something tells me that's a bad idea.

Thanks so much in advance for your time.  I have learned a lot from this community!
-GB

Comment: Try to limit your question to one language and one example.  Problem 1 would appear to be an issue with you understanding the difference between local and global variables.  Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415321/difference-between-static-auto-global-and-local-variable-in-the-context-of-c-a

Comment: How about learning C? This is treated in any book.

Comment: Thanks @pedwards that was very helpful.  I will also limit my questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're missing is called  "scope". It's not specific to XC8, any C book will help you.

PIC interrupts won't take/return anything for a reason. Define a global in the same file as your ISR is defined and read/change that. If you're going to write to it from the ISR declare it 'volatile':

```
volatile int foo = 0x00;
```

If you need to access it from another file (beginners shall avoid this) declare it 'extern' in this file (or include):

```
extern int foo;
```

Comment: Dear goodness thank you.  All I had to do was google "scope" and it all made sense.  Also, adding "volatile" to my declare was all I needed to do to get my interrupt working.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes behind, the code in PROBLEM 1 was actually working code.  My error instead was carelessly initializing my TRISC to 1 instead of 0xff; which means I was trying to run a button off an output.  I should know better than that.

However, I was having this problem on other occasions by declaring my variables in main(); instead of outside the functions.  This means I was trying to modify local variables inside a function that had not declared it - this was giving me nulls and garbage.  Pedwards correctly identified that I was having trouble with global vs local variables; and "scope" was a really helpful keyword.

Declaring a variable as volatile is necessary for the variable to be modified by the ISR.  After Oled's comment I was able to find this information on page 169 of the XC8 compiler manual.