# Does C have local bindings?

Tags: c, let

In some languages like `lisp` or `scheme` the programmer can define variables with `let` that are only available for a certain local scope. For example a function which is only called within another function.

Is there a C equivalent?

Comment: C uses `{..}` for scope naming. Any variable declared within a clock is local to that block.

Comment: If you use static outside any routines, the scope is only within that file.  If the static declaration is within a function, the value is *remembered* on re-entry.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: C variables are [`auto`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13415321/995714) by default and will not grow beyond their scope

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Plain wrong!

Comment: What does your C book say? What did you not understand?

Comment: I mean variables between brackets, not global ones

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: I commented on what you wrote, not what you "mean". Sorry, I'm no clairvoyant and beginners are mostly  also not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, variables are local to the scope of the wrapping { } brackets they are enclosed in.  This is the same in C++ and Java.

If a variable is defined outside of a function it is global to that module and can be referenced in other modules by adding an 'extern' prefix before the reference to the variable from another module in the module that wants to use it.

If a varaible is defined outside of a function and has the 'static' prefix then it is global to that module only.

When I say module this means everything contained in the same source file.  Java does not support global variables, however it does support static class variables which are almost the same as globals.

Answer (score -1):

Simply, if you want variable "count" has its own scope:

```
void test()
{

    int input;  //input is usable in function test() 
    ...

    {
        int count;  //count only usable in scope {}
        ...
    }
}
```