# C pointers and var scopes

Tags: c, pointers

I've a question about var scopes and pointer.
That's an example function:

```
int *double(int a)
{
    int p = a*2;
    int *ret = &p;

    return ret;
}
```

And that's the question: 
After a fuction return to the caller, it should delete from the memory every variable declared in it.

In this function I only return the addres of "p" (that's declared only in the function) but when I use it in the main, for example, the space of memory allocated by the function "double" hasn't been deleted.

Why?

Comment: Because `p`  is on the stack and only exists in the function. It have been deleted, what you are seing is probably just the leftover value that is considered invalid. Using it is undefined behavior

Comment: how do you know it hasnt been deleted?

Comment: No, I said that it exists even in the main when I access it by the address that my function returns.

Comment: This is UB afaik. It may or may not have been overwritten by the time you access it. Returning an address to a stack allocated variable should never be done.

Comment: No, because **undefined behavior** is *undefined*. `p` doesn't exist any more, but there's no obligation that your program changes whatever valuae is stored there. It could be overwritten any time by something different.

Comment: Good, so the function release that part of memory but it's possible that no one write over it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415321/difference-between-static-auto-global-and-local-variable-in-the-context-of-c-a

Comment: Sorry for the C++ dupe, but it's just a perfect match (with a great answer over there)

Comment: Obv that's not a problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The memory isn't valid anymore; what happens when you access it after `double` has returned is undefined behavior. That means that anything is possible:

1. It could be that the value hasn't been overwritten by something else yet (what likely happened in your case).
2. It could be that something else has written something to that address, so the value is now random garbage.
3. It could be that your code opens up a wormhole to a parallel dimension, causing an invasion of evil space octopi that dooms us all.

So, basically, I don't recommend it.

Comment: Now I should write a funct to close that wormhole, thank you for saving my life!

Comment: wormholes are the new [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), alright ;)