# Function giving precedence to GLOBAL variable instead of LOCAL - (Anomalous behaviour)

Tags: c++, function, scope, global-variables

I have:

1. `string s = "global"` [global scope]
2. `string s = "local"`  [local scope (main function)]

I want function `f1()` to print out the local `s` when it is called from `main`, but the function is printing the global `s` instead.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//global variables & functions .h

string s = "global";    void f1();

//main begins
int main()
{
    string s = "local";
    f1();

    return 0;
}

//function definitions .cpp

void f1()
{
    cout << s;
}
```

Output is:

```
global
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.281 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Ask yourself, how `f1` is supposed to see the `s` that's local to `main`.

Comment: `f1` doesn't know about the local `s` in `main`, and only sees the global `s`.  If you want `f1` to know about main's `s` you'll want to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415321/difference-between-static-auto-global-and-local-variable-in-the-context-of-c-a) for a broader discussion of name scope.

Comment: ```f1()``` should see the local ```s``` because ```std::cout``` sees it too.
*e.g.* if I type ```std::cout << s;``` in main, then it will output ```local```.
So, the question arises, why doesn't ```f1()``` exhibit the same behaviour?

Is it due to the implementation of ```std::cout```? It'd be super useful if somebody sheds some light on this fine point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the global definition is the only one visible to `f1`.  This is the difference between *lexical* and *dynamic* scoping, which I recommend you look up the definitions of.   C++ is *lexically* scoped, which means it can only see symbols based on where they're defined relative to the code.  `f1` can only see local variables defined inside it, and globals, it doesn't even know the variable in `main` exists.